# Fortran read statement reading sequence

Tags: file-io, fortran, gfortran

Suppose I have a file that each line contains an array index followed by the array value

```
i  array(i)
```

Can I read in the data by just a naive `read(unit=10, *) i, array(i)`? Will Fortran always read `i` first and then use this `i` value to assign `array(i)`? Will certain `read` specifications or compiler flags influence the behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data transfer statement

```
read(unit=10,*) i, array(i)
```

is a legitimate one, and its behaviour is as desired: from the record the value for `i` is first read, then that value is used to identify the element of the array `array(i)` for the second value read.

This is a requirement of the Fortran specification, such as with (Fortran 2018, 12.6.4.5.1):

> All values needed to determine which entities are specified by an input/output list item are determined at the beginning of the processing of that item.

Of course, although this data transfer statement potentially works, that doesn't mean that it is desirable in all but the simplest cases where you trust the input data.  In particular, it is not possible to do any checking of the bounds during this read statement.  If the `i` value read corresponds to an invalid array element specification, the program is broken.  You may want to use an intermediate value for the array element merely to handle potential problems with the input file.

Comment: I would even say that such code exposes a large vulnerability,  but that does not matter if it is a single use code used only by the author. Compiler flags for bounds checking are very strongly recommended.

Comment: "it is not possible to do any checking of the bounds during this read statement" - not sure I get this, especially why it is not possible, isn't it a quality of implementation issue rather than completely impossible? Or are you referring to "manual" checking by the programmer? If so it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, @IanBush, input validation by the programmer.  The usual bounds checking by compiler run-time being available, but usual in the sense of "I've noticed your program is broken, but I won't let you carry on thinking things are fine".

Comment: To check bounds, I would just use a temporary variable to store the array element: `read(unit=10,*) i, temp`. Then error check the bounds, then assign the array element to temp: `array(i) = temp`.